# How can i make a duplicate workbook that if i change something on the original sheet it will automatically update all the duplicate sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Can someone help me to make a duplicate sheet that if I change something on the original sheet it will automatically update all the duplicate?

For example: sheet 1 is my master file that contains list of items and their price and UOM on the next cells. Then I want to have another sheet that has exact the same content as my master file but if I change a name for example in the list, the duplicate also changes without me going one by one on each cell on the duplicate sheet typing:

```
='MASTER TEMPLATE'!C7
```

I hope you understood what I mean.

Comment: welcome to superuser. please note that this isn't a free code writing service, where we provide entire solutions, you also need to put some effort trying to solve the problem. Also your question isn't clear, what is the purpose of the duplication, how does it make sense to simply duplicate your data?

Comment: It sounds like you need a database rather than a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how much data you have, you can copy and paste the links (this doesn't require you to go one by one)

- Select Data
- Go to second sheet
- Right Click, Paste Special and select "Paste Links"

This will update as you make changes on sheet 1.

[image: Paste Special]

[image: Paste Link]